# Kibana timefilter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I am using kibana 4.1.2, and I created a dashboard line chart using “issue_time” (which has been recognized as date format in Elasticseach) as X-axis, and count as Y-axis. However, no matter how I change the time filter to whatever (like last 15 mins or last 30 mins, or last 1 hour), the line chart will not update and keeps showing me the data from when it was first configured.
Any advice will be very much appreciated.

[image: Screen shot 1]

[image: Screen shot 2]

Answer (score 0):

fixed, "time-field name" needs to be configured.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvcH1.png)